# Problems Deploying a ZF application on production server

Tags: php, zend-framework, deployment

I am trying to set up my first ZF (zf 1.11) application on a remote production server (JustHost). The app is working fine on my development server on a WAMP platform. My problem is that I have no idea how to deploy the app to my production server. And I have to say that I am stunned at how little info there is on the topic, either in the documentation or the community for what is such a crucial part of a project's lifecycle. I just want to copy my project folder to my server and get it working, thats all! But where do I put my `zf` folder, how do I point my application to the zf folder, what other configuration changes do I need to make? Can somebody please help me?

So far I have copied the `zf` folder and my project's folder to the server's public directory.

I have set the `.htaccess` application environment to production, and added my server's database info to the production section of the `application.ini` file.

At the moment when I naviaget to my project's folder in a browser I get a directory index of the folder's contents. When I navigate to the `/public/index.php` file I get an internal server error 500.

Comment: Check web server logs and php logs.  There should be some more info behind the Internal Server error you are seeing.  As for the migration... You understand how you got it working locally?  The file structure should be the same locally and in production no?  Probably just missing getting the ZF lib folder on PHP's path.  [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=zend+framewrok+php+path) should get plenty of results.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the logs and search regarding the zf library. On my local server my ZF folder is at C:\zf and included via my php.ini include path setting. I'm not sure if/how i can alter the php.ini on my production server as it is a commercial shared server.

Answer (score 0):

scure that the virtual host is config in right mode?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "path_name/public"
   ServerName domain.com

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

   <Directory "path_name/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks JellyBelly. I'm not sure if/hom my production server uses vhosts. I will have to investigate that, see if i can find something on my server's cpanel. I'm used to CI style projects where this kind of configuration isn't neccessary, its a bit confusing. Thanks for your response.